# Question about Intermediate Value Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

[image]

In the solution, it says that $f(a)\ge a$ and $f(b)\le b$  but it do not seem obvious for me. If I am just given that a $f:[a,b]\to[a,b]$, how do I know is this function increasing, decreasing or just a horizontal line?

Comment: The range of the function is $[a,b]$ means $\forall x \in [a,b]$, $a \le f(x) \le b$, so $f(a) \ge a$ and $f(b) \le b$.

Comment: Question: Isn't that the co-domain? How can we be sure that the function is surjective?

Comment: It doesn't have to be. For all $x$ by definition $f(x) \in [a,b]$ somewhere. This means $a\leq f(x) \leq b$. Including $f(a)$ and $f(b)$.

Comment: Certainly you do not know whether it is increasing, decreasing, or a horizontal line.  It could be any of those, or none.  But you don't need to know any of that in order to know that $f(a)\ge a$ or that $f(b)\le b$.  Those follow immediately from the fact that $f:[a,b]\to[a,b]$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 3):

Recall what $f:[a,b] \to [a,b]$ means. It means that given any $x \in [a,b]$, we know $f(x) \in [a,b]$. What does it mean for $f(x)$ to be in the interval $[a,b]$? That $a \leq f(x) \leq b$. For $a$, $a \leq f(a) \leq b$ and for $b$, $a \leq f(b) \leq b$. See that nothing about the shape or behavior of $f$ is required: just that the range, or image of $f$ is a subset of $[a,b]$.

Answer (score 2):

Just for the sake of completeness, here is an answer to the actual problem.

Consider a function  $g(x) = f(x) - x$. We want to show that

$$
\exists c \space g(c)=0 
$$

Now, $f(a) - a$ is necessarily non-negative, since $f(a) \geq a $ and similarly $f(b) - b$ is necessarily non-positive.

If either of these are $0$, then we are done and $c = a$ or $c = b$. If not, we have:

$$
f(a) - a > 0 > f(b) - b \\
g(a) > 0 > g(b)
$$

Thus by the IVT, we have $g(c) = 0$ for some $c \in [a, b]$, and thus $f(c) -c = 0$, or $f(c) = c$.

As you can see, you don't need to know that the function is increasing or decreasing or constant, the vital piece of information is that $f : [a, b] \rightarrow [a, b]$ as this implies $a \leq f(x) \leq b$.

Comment: I'd write $\exists c\ g(c)=0$, without "s.t.".  That is standard. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Ah, thank you. I'm still getting the hang of what is standard and conventions and the like.

Answer (score 0):

hint: draw a picture as follows:

(a) draw the square bounded by the lines $x = a, x = b, y = a$ and $y = b.$

(b) draw the diagonal line $y = x$

(c) draw the graph of the function $y = f(x)$ starting on the left edge of the square ending at the right edge because  $f: [a,b] \rightarrow [a,b]$

can you see that the function must cross the diagonal because it cannot escape through the bottom or the top of the square.

Answer (score 0):

Go by contradiction, let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow [a,b]$be continuous with no fixed point, so $\forall x\in[a,b]:f(x)\ne x$.

1. If you consider $a\in[a,b]$, then it has to follow $f(a)\ne a \Rightarrow f(a) > a$.
2. If there exists $x\in[a,b]$ such that $f(x) < x$, then continuity would imply $\exists x'\in[a,b]: f(x') = x'$, so $\forall x\in[a,b]:f(x) > x$.
3. Since $f(b)\in[a,b]$, either $f(b) = b$ or $f(b) < b$. First case is an instant contradiction, second case would follow (2) and give a contradiction.

So $f$ has to have a fixed point.